# SQL Server STUFF query with the SAME table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, temp-tables, stuff

I need to get the result like this:

[image: I need to fetch the result query as like below]

I have tried using this query:

```
SELECT
    STUFF((SELECT  ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), RuleNumber)
           FROM #tempSelectPlusReferralsExtracts v2
           WHERE v2.RuleApprovedDate IN
                 (CASE WHEN (v2.RuleApprovedDate IS NULL ) 
                    THEN NULL
                    ELSE v2.RuleApprovedDate
                    END
                  )
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') [Rules], 
    *  
FROM
    #tempSelectPlusReferralsExtracts
```

My result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: FYI, the "magic" isn't `STUFF` here; all `STUFF` is doing in the above is removing the first 2 characters from a string. `FOR XML PATH` is what is creating your comma delimited data.

Comment: As for the problem, seems like the `CASE` expression should be *around* your string aggregation, not within it.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you have? `select @@version`

Comment: Presumably (the completely unsupported) SQL Server 2008, @Charlieface , as that's what they've tagged.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned, seems your `CASE` expression should be around your string aggregation, not within it:

```sql
SELECT SPRE.RuleNumber,
       SPRE.RuleApprovedDate,
       CASE WHEN SPRE.RuleApprovedDate IS NULL THEN SPRE.RuleNumber
            ELSE STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(varchar(50), v2.RuleNumber)
                        FROM #tempSelectPlusReferralsExtracts v2
                        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,2,'')
       END AS [Rules]
FROM #tempSelectPlusReferralsExtracts SPRE;
```